# How to debug why icon is not displaying on Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Why the button icon on the right input is not displaying ?

I already included the material design icon script.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is the code **:**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<template id="mainbox">
  <v-card outlined>
    <v-list-item three-line>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <div class="text-overline mb-4">

          {{ title }}
        </div>
        <v-container>



          <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <div class="py-10"></div>
          <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
          <!-- TEST CODE -->
          <!-- --------- -->

          <v-row>
            <v-col md="6">


              <v-text-field label="Text ..." hint="write anything ... " v-model="item" append-icon="add" @click:append="add(item)"></v-text-field>
              <v-combobox clearable small-chips multiple :items="items" v-model="items"></v-combobox>


              <!-- {{ items}} -->

            </v-col>
          </v-row>










        </v-container>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-card>
</template>


<v-app id="app">
  <mainbox title="$CODE_08" />
</v-app>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const mainbox = Vue.component('mainbox', {
    template: '#mainbox',
    props: {
      title: String
    },
    data() {
      return {
        items: [],
        item: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      add(item) {
        console.log(item)
        this.items.push(item)
        this.item = ''
      }
    }
  });


  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    components: {
      mainbox
    }
  });

</script>
```

Screenshot **:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is, `add` is not an *material design icon* - first, you need to have the `mdi-` prefix,

so it would be

```
<v-text-field
  label="Text ..."
  hint="write anything ... "
  v-model="item"
  append-icon="mdi-add"
  @click:append="add(item)"></v-text-field>
```

however, `mdi-add` is also not a material design icon ... perhaps you want mdi-plus?

```
<v-text-field
  label="Text ..."
  hint="write anything ... "
  v-model="item"
  append-icon="mdi-plus"
  @click:append="add(item)"></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

`mdi-<icon-name>` is the default material design icon font for Vuetify input controls. Here is the [doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icons).

Also as [Bravo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10549313/bravo) said, we don't have any icon with named as `add` in material design. Hence, use either `plus` or `plus-thick` based on your requirement followed by `md-`.

Demo **:**

```js
const mainbox = Vue.component('mainbox', {
    template: '#mainbox',
    props: {
      title: String
    },
    data() {
      return {
        items: [],
        item: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      add(item) {
        console.log(item)
        this.items.push(item)
        this.item = ''
      }
    }
  });

  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    components: {
      mainbox
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<template id="mainbox">
  <v-card outlined>
    <v-list-item three-line>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <div class="text-overline mb-4">

          {{ title }}
        </div>
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col md="6">
              <v-text-field label="Text ..." hint="write anything ... " v-model="item" append-icon="mdi-plus" @click:append="add(item)"></v-text-field>
              <v-combobox clearable small-chips multiple :items="items" v-model="items"></v-combobox>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-card>
</template>


<v-app id="app">
  <mainbox title="$CODE_08" />
</v-app>
```